# How to get the explicit form of an estimated density function

Tags: r, kernel-density

I'm doing density estimation in R.

I am trying to use `density()` to do a kernel density estimation. After this, I want to evaluate its performance. However, some criteria require the knowledge of the explicit form of the estimated density function and I don't know how to get it.

Currently, I'm thinking of using data points and their densities to express the estimated density function approximately (like a piecewise function).

Is there a better way to do this? More generally, is it possible to retrieve the explicit form of a function based on its graph in R?

**Update:**

Consider this criteria:

ISE=Integral[(f_hat-f)^2]

where f_hat is the estimated density and f is the true density.

Comment: it doesn't really have an explicit form; its value at any point y is defined by the kernel-weighted sum over points in the data set.  (This *might* be a better question for CrossValidated).  Can you be more explicit about the criteria you want to evaluate that require the explicit form of the function?

Comment: Does that mean I can only approach the estimated density function using the method I proposed above?@Ben Bolker

Comment: It would help if you could add more detail to your question.  What are the criteria you want to evaluate, and how/where are they implemented?  In principle you could write a function (or maybe one already exists somewhere) that takes a vector and returns a function that evaluates the kernel density at a specified point ...

Comment: Please refer to the update for the criteria I want to use.@Ben Bolker

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with the `kde1d` package. The main function of this package is `kde1d`. It is better than `density` to estimate a density.

```
library(kde1d)

set.seed(666)
x <- rnorm(100) # simulate some data
fit <- kde1d(x) # estimate density
d <- dkde1d(0, fit) # evaluate density estimate at 0
d
# 0.383205
dnorm(0)
# 0.3989423
```

The function is vectorized:

```
d <- dkde1d(c(-1,0,1), fit)
d
# 0.2675120 0.3832050 0.2213388
```

Comment: Why is it better than the base KDE? How is this an explicit form for the density function any more than that available from base KDE?

Comment: @alanocallaghan Try to estimate a decreasing density with `density`, for example `density(rbeta(100, 0.5, 3))`. You will see that it is badly estimated. This is not the case with `kde1d`. I don't see which function you mean "available from base KDE".

Comment: `density` as you mentioned in your answer. It's the 1d KDE available in base

Comment: @alanocallaghan `density` returns two numeric vectors `x` and `y` AFAIK, not a function.

Comment: It's trivial to make that a function by 2d interpolation, and that's as much of an explicit form as kde1d provides. I don't doubt that kde1d has advantages over `density` but it might be useful to state them, rather than just claiming generic superiority

Comment: @alanocallaghan Of course, one can use `approxfun` or `splinefun`. But these provide functions only defined on the range of `x`, while `dkde1d` allows to evaluate the density outside the range of `x`.